# Should I track time for an hourly project during time taking operations?

Tags: time-tracking, hourly

I am a freelance programmer and use time-tracker software to bill my hours. Sometimes when I am running some time-taking operation such as building a Docker image, running a CI pipeline and waiting for it to finish. Should I keep the time tracker running while I am waiting and using apps like YouTube, Discord in the meantime?

Comment: Those are issues that should be addressed with your client, not us. Better yet, they should be spelled out in your contract.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here I can suggest two approaches:-

1. Use another machine during such hours to watch youtube, etc.
2. These types of tasks require monitoring in between, so in a way, you should still clock hours. However, these should be cleared beforehand in your contract with the employer.